# Substitute Win7 USB drivers for ADB mode

Tags: usb, adb, windows, advent-amico

Under Mac OSX there is no need for a USB driver for ADB mode.  Under windows, apparently, there is.

I'd like to be able to `adb shell` to my android tablet from my Win7 PC.

[This table](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html) gives a list of where to get USB drivers for Windows for different OEMs.  My Android Advent Amico tablet's manufacturer isn't listed in the list.  Is there a list of what can substitute for what somewhere?  How, in general, can one determine which one(s) would be best to try?

**EDIT:**
The tablet came with a utility called 'Advent Transfer Companion' for use in mass storage mode.  I've uploaded and installed that from the tablet, but it appears to be no more than a pretty way to write files to the tablet from PC - i.e. mass storage mode only, and no USB driver installed.

Comment: Did your tablet come with any PC software of its own (like for syncing, etc)? Usually that will include a USB driver & should be enough...

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/enable-adb-usb-drivers-for-nvidia-tegra-based-android-tablets/) says you should be able to use the "google drivers" after some minor tweaking. If your device came with any software for your PC, it will have the "official" drivers though, and I recommend using them.

> 1. You must have Android SDK installed before you can proceed. If
>      you don’t have it already, proceed to
>      our guide on what is ADB and how to
>      install it. Make sure you download the
>      Google USB Driver Package as well.
> 2. Open the google-usb_driver folder that you will find inside your Android
>      SDK folder.
> 3. Open the android_winusb.inf file in notepad or any text editor to edit
>      it.
> 4. Add these lines under [Google.NTx86] or [Google.NTamd64]
>      depending on whether you are using 32
>      bit or 64 bit Windows. If unsure, it
>      is safe to add these under both these
>      sections.
>
> > ;NVIDIA Tegra
> >     %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0955&PID_7000
> >     %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0955&PID_7100&MI_01
>
> Don’t edit or replace any other
>   text that is already there; just add
>   these new lines and save the file.
>
> 1. Open a command prompt window and enter this command:
>
> > echo 0x955 >> "%USERPROFILE%.android\adb_usb.ini"

You will also have to enable USB Debugging in Settings -> Applications -> Development.

**edit** I would try this first:

[This site](http://www.myadventvega.co.uk/) has the "official" [drivers](http://www.myadventvega.co.uk/SystemUSB.zip) for the tablet. You will still have to enable USB debugging, as I mentioned above.

Comment: It's an Advent Amico.  Those 'official' drivers are for Advent Vega.  Whether or not that is the issue, they don't install.  Windows says "windows could not find driver software for your device", even though I point it at that (unpacked using 7-zip) folder.