# Device recognition on Android SDK

Tags: adb, 1.5-cupcake, android-sdk

I've got a Chinese aPad running Android 1.5, how do I get it to be recongnised by Android SDK? I want to do `adb` hacks as recommended by [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6279/replacing-android-on-apad-with-other-linux-distro/6294#6294). Pointers to using `adb` also welcome.

Comment: You forgot to link to the answer mentioned in your question.

Comment: Is the aPad "Google approved"?  I thought it didn't pass Google's [Comaptibility Test Sheet](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html).

Comment: @Daniel, my bad.

Comment: @Matthew, no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the PC you've got the SDK installed on is running Windows, the first step to getting your device recognized by the SDK/ADB is having the right Windows USB drivers for your device installed.

See this previous question for more on getting hold of the right ADB drivers for your device: [Substitute Win7 USB drivers for ADB mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/)